# IOS 8 ScrollView fixed content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8

Hi I am developing an IOS application. Also using scrollview. As I encountered a problem on the iOS version 8. I added in the following way scroll the content inside. Scroll back in the first picture looks steady. Other images normally scrolling.

```
NSArray *aImageUrls = (NSArray *)[_dataSource arrayWithImageUrlStrings];
    if([aImageUrls count] > 0)
    {
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * [aImageUrls count],
                                               _scrollView.frame.size.height)];

        for (int i = 0; i < [aImageUrls count]; i++)
        {
            CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
            [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [imageView setContentMode:[_dataSource contentModeForImage:i]];
            [imageView setTag:i];
            [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)[aImageUrls objectAtIndex:i]]];

            // Add GestureRecognizer to ImageView
            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                                  initWithTarget:self
                                                                  action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
            [singleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
            [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }

        [_countLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[_dataSource arrayWithImageUrlStrings] count]]];
        _pageControl.numberOfPages = [(NSArray *)[_dataSource arrayWithImageUrlStrings] count];
        _pageControl.hidden = ([(NSArray *)[_dataSource arrayWithImageUrlStrings] count] > 0?NO:YES);
    }
```

[image: first picture in scrollview]
[image]

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @aoneki please elaborate you prob, we are not getting the actual problme

Comment: Yeah, you haven't actually asked a question here. You need to tell us what is going wrong and what you would like it to do instead, etc...